# How To Test Unstructured Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, unit-testing, qunit

I'm faced with trying to add testing to a lot of code like the following. I know I can use mockjax to to intercept the ajax calls. But I don't how to test the `$.ajax({...})` calls in isolation. I'd appreciate a good refactoring approach, but I'd also like to avoid rewriting the entire app.

I've gotten a start in other areas using qunit, and I like it. But I'm open to other suggestions too. How should I proceed?

```
function submitSync(repFrom, continuousRep, storedPassword) {
    // var repTriggered = false;
    if (repFrom !== '' && (storedPassword !== null || storedPassword !== "")) {
        var secureHome = "http://" + homeUser + ":" + storedPassword + "@" + window.location.host + "/" + homeURL;
        var theSource = repFrom.split("/");
        var singleDocumentReplication = (theSource.length === 5);



        /*
        * DELETE existing replications. There will normally be no more than 1.
        * Do not delete replications for application updates.
        * Note that we don't allow the user to create continuous replications.
        */

        $.getJSON(currentHost + '/_replicator/_all_docs', function (data) {
            $.each(data.rows, function (i, theRow) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: currentHost + '/_replicator/' + theRow.id,
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    async: false,
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function (doc) {
                        if (doc._id !== "_design/_replicator" && (typeof doc.source !== 'undefined' && !doc.source.match(onlineBase + '/' + remoteDB))) {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "/_replicator/" + doc._id + "?rev=" + doc._rev,
                                type: "DELETE",
                                contentType: "application/json",
                                success: function () {
                                    console.log('Replication deleted: ' + doc._id + '?rev=' + doc._rev);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });

        if (singleDocumentReplication) {
            var theDoc = theSource[4];
            var repFromBase = repFrom.substr(0, repFrom.indexOf(theDoc) - 1);

            $.ajax({
                url: "/_replicator",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify({ "source": repFromBase, "target": secureHome,
                    "userCtx": { "name": homeUser, "roles": ["_admin", homeUser] },
                    "continuous": continuousRep,
                    "retries_per_request": 10,
                    "http_connections": 3,
                    "doc_ids": [theDoc]
                }),
                contentType: "application/json",
                error: function () {                    
                    dialog(libLang.noSync);
                },
                success: function (message) {
                    if (message) {                        
                        dialog(libLang.synced);
                    }
                    repTriggered = true;
                }
            });

        } else {

            $.ajax({
                url: "/_replicator",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify({ "source": repFrom, "target": secureHome,
                    "userCtx": { "name": homeUser, "roles": ["_admin", homeUser] },
                    "continuous": continuousRep,
                    "retries_per_request": 10,
                    "http_connections": 3
                }),
                contentType: "application/json",
                error: function () {                    
                    dialog(libLang.noSync);
                },
                success: function (message) {
                    if (message) {                        
                        dialog(libLang.synced);
                    }
                    repTriggered = true;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've got a ton of code duplication. My recommendation would be to put your ajax calls into modules and pass the `$.ajax` as a dependency.

So:

```
function myModule(ajaxDependency, anyOtherDependency) { }
```

This way in your unit test you simply check to make sure your dependecies behave a certain way. And it looks like it will eliminate all your DRY issues.

Comment: Doing that and using mockjax to intercept the ajax calls works perfectly.